# Fixed layout scroll horizontal like Google Plus

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, google-plus

I'd like to create a layout similar to Google Plus.

Now I have a question about the fixed elements. If you scroll down, only the white content area scrolls. The menu, the top area and the sidebar stay fixed. That's not the problem.

But as soon as you change the width of the browser window and make it very thin, you can scroll horizontal anyway to see the "overflow".

Now, how could I implement this with CSS, maybe also with jQuery? Fixed elements never scroll. On Google Plus, they do, if the window isn't wide enough.

My page is [givget.de](http://givget.de)!
So please let me know, if there is any possibility to do this!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I fixed all elements with CSS except the content. Now, if you scroll down, only the content moves. My layout isn't flexible. It has a width about 1100px. At the moment, horizontal overflow is hidden, because if you scroll horizontal, everything falls apart.

Comment: What you're looking to do is a type of responsive design check out ['resposnive design roundup'](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/09/the-ultimate-responsive-web-design-roundup/). You just need to check the window's width either with media queries or javascript and modify the div's positioning CSS attributes

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started, you'd want to do something like

```
var minWidth = 1000;
....

$(window).resize(function(e){
    if($(window).width() < minWidth){
       $('.fixedSidebar').css('position','relative'); // etc
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, but on an 11"-Notebook I still have the problem, that the screen can't show the full width of my content. It has just 1024px! So, the user should have the possibility to scroll horizontal without destroying my layout. I wished that the complete layout (incl. navigation, top area etc.) moves left. Not just the content like on srolling vertical.

Comment: To do something like that, you need to have a fixed-width div inside a smaller, flexible one with `overflow-x` set to `scroll`. For example, if you had div a inside div b, and div a's width was set to 2000px (bigger than your 11" screen) and set to float left, and div b was set to a width of 100% with overflow-x: scroll, you'd get that effect.

Comment: It seems that this doesn't have the desired effect. Now, like before, the white content scrolls out of the screen on the left. But the fixed elements with "position: fixed" stay on there place. I would like to have the whole layout to move out/scroll. But only horizontal.